# Converting upper 128 characters in Python from subprocess.popen() to use in JSON

Tags: python, unicode, encoding

I'm calling `subprocess.popen()` on the [xpdf](http://www.foolabs.com/xpdf/) program pdfinfo, which is returning text including some characters in the upper half of the 8-bit character set.

I pass the result to a JSON serializer and it is complaining when it gets to character `\xae` (the ® sign):

```
>>> import json
>>> json.dumps({'a':'Adobe\xae'})
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\app\python\2.7.3\lib\json\__init__.py", line 231, in dumps
    return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
  File "c:\app\python\2.7.3\lib\json\encoder.py", line 201, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "c:\app\python\2.7.3\lib\json\encoder.py", line 264, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xae in position 5: invalid start byte
```

How can I fix this? I am totally confused about codecs and where I'm supposed to add the right information to help Python figure out how to deal with it.

---

Edit: If the input is from *me* (or at least my source code), not another process, I could just use a Unicode string literal

```
>>> json.dumps({'a':u'Adobe\u00ae'})
'{"a": "Adobe\\u00ae"}'
```

and Python would handle it fine.

But I don't know what hint to give Python to decode the output of pdfinfo as Unicode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to figure out what the character encoding of the data you're getting back is.  I'm guessing that it's [Windows-1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252), which has the symbol "®" at code point 0xAE.  So, to decode that, you would use the [`str.decode`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.decode) function:

```
raw_data = 'Adobe\xae'
decoded = raw_data.decode('Windows-1252')
print decoded  # Prints "Adobe®"
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a parameter `ensure_ascii` for json encoding.

```
>>> json.dumps({'a':u'Adobe\u00ae'}, ensure_ascii=False)
u'{"a": "Adobe\xae"}'
>>> print json.dumps({'a':u'Adobe\u00ae'}, ensure_ascii=False)
{"a": "Adobe®"}
```

If `ensure_ascii` is `False`, the result may contain non-ASCII characters and the return value may be a unicode instance.

Answer (score 0):

@Adam's answer on str.decode gave me a hint. Also, the `pdfinfo` program thankfully accepts a parameter for encoding (`-enc [encoding]`) parameter so I can do `-enc UTF-8` and then use

```
raw_data.decode('UTF-8')
```

in Python.